# Unix ksh loop and put the result into variable

Tags: unix, shell

I have a simple thing to do, but I'm novice in UNIX.
So, I have a file and on each line I have an ID.
I need to go through the file and put all ID's into one variable.

I've tried something like in Java but does not work.

```
for variable in `cat myFile.txt`
do
    param=`echo "${param} ${variable}"`
done
```

It does not seems to add all values into param.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

```
param=$(<myFile.txt)
```

The parameter has white space (actually newlines) between the names.  When used without quotes, the shell will expand those to spaces, as in:

```
cat $param
```

If used with quotes, the file names will remain on separate lines, as in:

```
echo "$param"
```

Note that the Korn shell special-cases the '`$(<file)`' notation and does not fork and execute any command.

Also note that your original idea can be made to work more simply:

```
param=
for variable in `cat myFile.txt`
do
    param="${param} ${variable}"
done
```

This introduces a blank at the front of the parameter; it seldom matters.  Interestingly, you can avoid the blank at the front by having one at the end, using `param="${param}${variable} "`.  This also works without messing things up, though it looks as though it jams things together.  Also, the '`${var}`' notation is not necessary, though it does no harm either.

And, finally for now, it is better to replace the back-tick command with '`$(cat myFile.txt)`'.  The difference becomes crucial when you need to nest commands:

```
perllib=$(dirname $(dirname $(which perl)))/lib
```

vs

```
perllib=`dirname \`dirname \\\`which perl\\\`\``/lib
```

I know which I prefer to type (and read)!

Comment: It looks fine your piece of code, but the same result. I only have the last line and the half of the one before.
What can be wrong with my txt file?

Comment: @CC: CRLF line endings?  As in, the file comes from DOS, so what you see in the variable is '`name1\rlongername\rn3`' with the output showing just 'n3ngername'.  '`\r`' represents a carriage return.

Comment: I got it. Actually my txt file was not in UNIX format. I just opened the file and choosed UNIX format from my editor. I guess there must have been some special characters not visibles.

Thanks alot everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
param=`cat myFile.txt | tr '\n' ' '`
```

The `tr` command `tr`anslates all occurrences of `\n` (new line) to spaces. Then we assign the result to the param variable.

Lovely.

Comment: Something is missing.
In my file I have something like that:
.......
AAA_4436188
37935

In the param all I have is 3793536188, so the last line and the half of the one before.

Comment: Can you post a fuller snippet of the file?

Comment: It was a DOS file with CR messing things up - see comments below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
var=$(awk '1' ORS=" " file)
```

ksh

```
 while read -r line
 do
   t="$t $line"
 done < file
 echo $t
```

Comment: Actually to display it, it works, but I cannot put it into a variable/
I'm able to display all the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
param="$(< myFile.txt)"
```

or

```
while read line
do
    param="$param$line"$'\n'
done < myFile.txt
```